# JSON_Encode outputting odd extra values

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json

I am running a MySQL query that retrieves some data from my database in the form of an array. I am then encoding this data to JSON format and echo'ing this to my web page.

My issue is that the JSON_Encode seems to give me extra key-value pairs and I'm not sure why. I have checked my array does not contain this extra data.

The output I would expect to see is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "fullname": "John Smith",
        "username": "jsmith"
    }
]
```

But the output I am receiving is:

```
[
    {
        "0": "1",
        "id": "1",
        "1": "John Smith",
        "fullname": "John Smith",
        "2": "jsmith",
        "username": "jsmith"
    }
]
```

Anyone have any idea where this is coming from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what your query and db rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the array going into `json_encode()`. Is it an array coming back from a call to `mysql_fetch_array` or a similar function? If so, you might want to consider using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead; it will give you the same data back, but will only have the associative indexes, rather than both.